# unable to import win32com.client

Tags: python, python-2.7, winapi

I am trying to import win32com.client library gives me the following error:

```
>>> import win32com.client

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#57>", line 1, in <module>
     import win32com.client
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\win32com\__init__.py", line 5, in  
    <module>       
    import win32api, sys, os
ImportError: No module named win32api
>>>
```

Basically i am trying to send email using win32com.client .
Kindly help.

Answer (score 0):

Did you install the [Win32 Extensions for Python](http://python.net/crew/skippy/win32/Downloads.html)? Make sure you pick the correct installer for your system and version of Python otherwise it may not work correctly.

Comment: Yes i did install the pywin32-220.win32-py2.7.exe package from the win32 Extensions, still getting the same error.

Answer (score 0):

Prob selved by uninstalling all python version and installing one only